# pass a dataURL through AJAX

Tags: mysql, ajax, html, canvas, data-url

I'm attempting to save a dataURL made from an HTML5 canvas to my mysql db.

I have ajax setup to pull the var I've made called "dataURL" and I'm setting dataURL to the canvas's img using this code:

```
dataURL = oCanvas.toDataURL();
```

my issue is the canvas's dataURL has alot of characters that don't work well in pulling for ajax so I need a way to encode it or manipulate it differently so my end result can be saved to a mysql db and then later "decoded" to display once again.

I know my AJAX works because if I set the var dataURL to something like "cheese" it saves in the database as cheese.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up setting an event so when the image was done drawing it would set the dataURL to a hidden form element. No longer needed to pass it through ajax :). Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

The data you receive from toDataUrl will be in a format like this:

```
 data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD.... (very long string)
```

Firstly filter the data received to only the part after `data:image/png;base64,`

Then use whatever Base64 library your language provides to decode it to an array of bytes (or blob). If you are using Java: [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/)

Here is an example in groovy:

```
def bytes = new Base64().decode(filteredData) as byte[]
```

You can save the decoded result to your database (to be retrieved later)

Answer (score 0):

Base64 encoding takes almost 4x as many bytes to encode an image. It is suggested to use [window.atob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.atob) to decode the base64 before transmission whether you are using ajax or regular forms. Of course IE doesn't support it but [this looks like a shim](http://code.google.com/p/stringencoders/source/browse/trunk/javascript/base64.js?r=230).